# Como adicionar um Scrollbar para um Frame em tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, rolamento

Eu tenho uma tabela, criada em um `Frame`, que pode ficar muito grande e ultrapassar o tamanho do monitor do usuário. Por isso, eu preciso criar um `Scrollbar` para ele. Para fins de demonstração, vamos supor que minha aplicação seja essa:

```
class MyList(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.__build()

    def __build(self):
        for i in range(300): Label(self, text = "Olá Mundo! Pela %i vez..." % i).pack()

window = Tk()
my_list = MyList(window)
my_list.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

O problema é que eu recentemente descobri que não é possível adicionar `Scrollbar` para frames. Ou seja, o código abaixo não é válido:

```
scroll_bar = Scrollbar(window)
scroll_bar.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')

my_list.config(yscrollcommand = scroll_bar.set)
scroll_bar.config(command = my_list.yview)
```

Ainda assim, há pessoas em alguns sites, em inglês, falando que existem maneiras de fazer isso com `Canvas` e outros widgets. Mas ainda não entendi muito bem isso. Então minha dúvida é: como eu faço para adicionar a `Scrollbar` para o `Frame`?

Comment: Não é possivel? Será que não foi falta só do `frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)` ?

Comment: Como assim @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para que você compreenda melhor o problema.

Comment: Então, a resposta direta é: não dá pra adicionar Scrollar no Frame, como você mesmo concluiu. A maneira de resolver é: crie um Canvas, coloque o Frame no Canvas e o Scrollbar no Canvas

Comment: @FlavioMoraes Mas é essa a questão. Como que eu faço isso?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 , postei a resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do seu Frame crie um canvas e dentro do canvas um outro Frame. Tem umas complicações extras, mas o código abaixo deve funcionar:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyList(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_propagate(False)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

        self.scroll_bar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.scroll_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll_bar.set)
        
        self.internal_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.internal_frame, anchor='nw')

        self.__build()
        self.internal_frame.update_idletasks()

        self.config(width=300,height=300)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def __build(self):
        for i in range(300): Label(self.internal_frame, text = "Olá Mundo! Pela %i vez..." % i).pack()

window = Tk()
my_list = MyList(window)

window.mainloop()
```

*Edição: expandindo o frame interno para o tamanho do canvas*

A ideia aqui é ler o tamanho do canvas e passar para o frame interno.

Primeiro, é importante ressaltar que o frame interno não foi colocado com um pack, mas como um item do canvas, e vamos precisar do id dele. Por isso vamos pegar o id dele alterando a linha

```
self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.internal_frame, anchor='nw')
```

por

```
self.frame_id = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.internal_frame, anchor='nw')
```

Agora, para alterar o tamanho do Frame interno podeos usar:

```
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width = self.canvas.winfo_width())
```

Se você quiser ir mais longe e considerar que a janela pode mudar de tamanho, você precisa usar um `bind` que detecta alterações de tamanho do master:

```
self.master.update()
self.resize(None)
self.master.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
```

então definimos a função `resize`:

```
def resize(self, event):
    self.config(width=self.master.winfo_width(),height=self.master.winfo_height())
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.frame_id, width = self.winfo_width())
```

Só pra explicar, eu precisei fazer uma "malandragem" pro código funcionar. Como o master vai ser reajustado de tamanho quando o Frame for criado, e o tamanho inicial dele é zero, eu preciso criar o Frame antes de fazer o bind, e por isso eu usei o `self.master.update()`. Mas ao fazer isso, eu não faço o resize do Frame para o master no começo, então eu chamo a função resize, que recebe um parâmetro `event`, e por isso eu mandei ´None`.

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente. O problema é que o `Frame` não está expandindo dentro do `Canvas`.

Comment: Só para que fique claro, não fui eu que dei downvote na sua resposta.

Comment: Qual Frame não está expandindo? O Frame externo está limitado pelo tamanho de 300x300 em `self.config(width=300,height=300)`. Ele não expande automaticamente por causa do comando `self.grid_propagate(False)`. O canvas ocupa todo o espaço dele por causa do `sticky="news"`

Comment: Essa questão do downvote aqui no stack em português é muito chata. Todas as perguntas recebem downvote e a galera parece que tem preguiça de responder. Se a pergunta tá mal feita, ao invés de ajudarem, denunciam a pergunta. As respostas a galera dá downvote sem comentar... sei lá qual é a do pessoal aqui

Comment: Eu me refiro ao Frame dentro do Canvas. Eu preciso que o Frame dentro do Canvas se expanda, da mesma forma quando eu utilizo `pack(fill = "both", expand = True)`.

Comment: entendi, vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 deu trabalho para fazer funcionar caso o tamanho da janela mudasse, mas está aí o código

Comment: Está funcionando Flávio. Obrigado. Só tem um detalhezinho. O Frame acaba ocupando alguns pixels a mais do Canvas. No caso, uma parte da direita do Frame está saindo cortada. Eu consegui corrigir meio que na gambiarra, subtraindo 2 do `width`.

Comment: curioso. Pode ser algo relacionado com as bordas da janela. Se eu não me engano as bordas das janelas no windows tem 4pixels